# Laravel Dynamic Filesystem Configuration Set in Controller Level

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filesystem, laravel-service-container, laravel-config

I'm trying to set filesystem configuration value dynamically in controller level. (I think it's almost impossible).

For example:

```
    'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
        'port' => intval(env('SFTP_PORT')),
        'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),
    ],
```

This is my SFTP disk configuration value in `filesystems.php`.

I will have `host, port, username, password` values dynamically from database table. (There will be multiple records.)

And I'm trying to connect File System using File Manager Package. (ie: https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-file-manager)

When I used static values, it worked well.

Now I'm trying to set it dynamically in Controller level.

```
$myConfigArrayvalue = MyModel::find($id);
config(['filesystems.disk.sftp' => $myConfigArrayvalue);
```

When I `dd(config('filesystems.disk.sftp'))` in controller or view, it shows dynamically value.

but in File Manager Package (ServiceProvider), it was showing empty value so when I go to view page, it didn't work.

I think this is because ServiceProvider was called before Controller.

Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Comment: you are setting these config values in what controller?

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this issue recently, after some research, I found that we can use `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager` to create the sftp connection dynamically.

Here is how I do it:

```
            $config = [
                         'driver'   => 'sftp',
                         'host'     => $host,
                         'port'     => $port,
                         'username' => $username,
                         'password' => $password,
                      ];
            $fsMgr = new FilesystemManager(app());
            $sftpDisk = $fsMgr->createSftpDriver($config);
            $sftpDisk->put($fileName, $fullTxt);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!